# Reinstall Python into same virtualenv while keeping modules intact

Tags: python, virtualenv

I think there may be a problem with my Python 2.7.10 install inside of a `virtualenv`.

I would like to reinstall just the Python 2.7.10 ‘core’ files from Homebrew (OS X), while keeping all my other files/modules (`site-packages`, etc) intact.

Is it possible to reinstall/overwrite just the core Python files inside of a `virtualenv` while keeping the rest of its contents intact? I.e. not having to delete and recreate the entire virtual environment.

Comment: For simple reinstall you can do `pip freeze` save to a file (eg req.txt) and reinstall later with `pip install -r req.txt`

Comment: But that requires redownloadiing/rebuildingeverything